# convert raw string source to html to use jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this source

```
&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

How can I convert it to html and use selector like `$('.page')` ? I tried to assign above string to a variable then use `html()` it doesn't work.

Comment: Does your string really have those character entities in it? That seems odd.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have no control over the source

Comment: That's not what I asked you. I asked if it really contained the character entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **parse** your string in HTML, after that if you look the object returned, there's a `data` property on the first row who contain the html string with good format.

**EDIT**

You can get HTML object properties without append it to the DOM. Check my edited code.

```
var test = '&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
var testHTML = $.parseHTML(test);
var elemHTML = $(testHTML[0].data);

console.log(elemHTML.text());
```

You can try this :

```js
var test = '&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
var testHTML = $.parseHTML(test);
$("body").html(testHTML[0].data);
$(".page").css("color","blue");

//Without append element in the DOM
var elemHTML = $(testHTML[0].data);

console.log(elemHTML.text());

//For count number of element you can use a container without append it to the DOM

var container=$("<div></div>");
container.append(elemHTML);
console.log(container.find(".page").length);
```

```css
.page{
 color:red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why can't I do $(testHTML).find('.page').length?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: Because the result of `$(testHTML)` is a jQuery object with a `div` at the top level. There are no `.page` elements *inside* that `div`, so `.find(".page")` doesn't find any. (The `div` itself is the one with the `page` class.)

Comment: testHTML is a big object returned by the `$.parseHTML()`. I've succeed the `$(".page")` selector juste because i've append the html in the body.

Comment: so I must create a 'fake' div? i don't want to append the str to anywhere to the DOM.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: If you want to use `find`, yes, you'll need a wrapper. Whether that's a `div` or `body` or... Alternately you could do `var x = $(testHTML); x = x.find(".page").add(x.filter(".page"));`

Comment: It depend, what you want to do with your element ? Which data you want recover ? You need it only for the case mentionned by @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: There's a working example of how to do this in my answer. There's nothing wrong with a wrapper element.

Comment: @Alexis why the length of the class is zero? http://jsbin.com/tarigeseca/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I can't access to Jsbin. if you are trying `$(".page").length` it's normal, as we tell you, it only count the number of element in the DOM who have the class `.page`. And you don't want append it.

Comment: how can I check how many class that named 'page' without appending to the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

See comments, first we have to process the entities, then use the result as HTML:

```js
// The string
var str = '&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
// A wrapper element to put it in
var wrapper = $("<body>");
// Process the character entities
wrapper.html(str);
str = wrapper.text();
// Convert the resulting HTML to a structure
wrapper.html(str);
console.log("Text of .page: ", wrapper.find(".page").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That's verbose for clarity; here's the concise version:

```js
var str = '&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
var wrapper = $("<body>");
wrapper.html(wrapper.html(str).text());
console.log("Text of .page: ", wrapper.find(".page").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Alexis: About what? Your code works. It does append it to the page, which wasn't my impression of what the OP wanted, but I could easily just have the wrong impression... But using `$.parseHTML` is probably cleaner than my `div` above...

Comment: I see. I confess I do not know either. In view of your reply I thought I was mistaken.

Comment: this is too much of code @T.J.Crowder, but why I can't do` $(x).find('.page')` after I used $.parseHTML like `var x = parseHTML(str);`

Comment: @NatelyJamerson: I've kept the parts separate just for clarity. I answered your `.find` question where you asked it on Alexis' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script for this

```
$('.page').html('&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
```

**or**

```
var htmlString = '&lt;div class="page"&gt;&lt;h1&gt;First Page &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
$('.page').html(htmlString);
```

Jquery automatically convert it to html

Comment: i do not want to append to anywhere in the DOM